# Is there a way to clear data in a sheet from another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a "Master Sheet" where I merge multiple workbooks where data is inputted (Station workbooks) into one Master file.I would like to clear the data in the Station workbooks when I press a command button in the Master Sheet, clearing all the data and saving as today's date. It also needs to erase specific ranges in the workbooks...

I tried and it works when I clear the data only within the Master Sheet, but the code I tried involving the other sheets seems to be stuck. I used array to erase from multiple workbooks. I only tried it in Station 1 file.

```
 Sub ClearAll()

 'ClearAll & Save Macro

 Dim answer As Integer

 answer = MsgBox("All entries will be cleared. Are you sure?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")



If answer = vbYes Then

'clears station data

Dim ex As Excel.Application
Dim wrkbk As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim books As Variant
Dim folder As String
Dim i As Integer

folder = "C:\Users\arocmag\Documents\MasterLog"
books = Array("Station 1 Daily Log.xlsm")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error GoTo errH:
Set ex = New Excel.Application
For i = 0 To UBound(books)
    Set wrkbk = ex.Workbooks.Open(folder & books(i))
    Set sht = wrkbk.Sheets(1)
    sht.Range("A2:H2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    wrkbk.Close True
Next
ex.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
errH:
ex.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox Err.Description



'clears Master Sheet
Range("A2:H2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("I1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Log").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Selection.AutoFilter

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\arocmarg\Documents\Rotation 3 - Warehouse Leader\01 - Capstone\6_20_2019\MasterLog" & " " & Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsm")


Else
 'do nothing
 End If


 End Sub
```

I want the station files to be cleared and SAVED (not saved as) + master file to be cleared and SAVED AS.

Comment: `Set ex = New Excel.Application` - no need for this - you can use the existing instance where your code is running. So `Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Open(folder & books(i))` for example

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a backslash:
Change:

```
folder = "C:\Users\arocmag\Documents\MasterLog"
```

to

```
folder = "C:\Users\arocmag\Documents\MasterLog\"
```

Also, nice error handling with the ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts.  Too often people don't handle those correctly.

You also don't need to be doing the "Selects".  The section

```
sht.Range("A2:H2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

can be simplified to:

```
Range(sht.Range("A2:H2"), sht.Range("A2:H2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

Read up on avoiding "Selects" in VBA and you'll end up with much simpler code that executes much faster.